# How to keep login with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have tried to retrieve a cookie from a logged-in account (sessionId) and then assign it in JS. However, when I tried to run the code, it forced me to log in. How can I bypass the login (using the previously logged-in cookie)

```
import puppeteer from "puppeteer";
const width = 1080;
const height = 1024;
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  headless: false,
});
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36');
await page.goto("https://briansclub.cm/cvv/",{waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});
const name = await page.$eval("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']", (input) => {
  return input.getAttribute("value");
});
console.log(name);
const cookies = [
  {
    name: "sessionid",
    value: "4a1fatg96pkisqew7iv5hzikyif41qtn",
    domain: "briansclub.cm",
    path: "/",
    httpOnly: false,
    secure: true, 
  },
  {
    name: "csrftoken",
    value: name,
    domain: "briansclub.cm",
    path: "/",
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: true, 
  },
];
await page.setCookie(...cookies);
```